# rewrite a base R function with dplyr - utilizing filter instead of []

Tags: r, function, dplyr

```
makeparts <- function(x, n) {
  x <- unique(c(0, x))
  x <- x[x >= 0 & x < n]
  x <- x[order(x)]
  x <- rep(c(seq_along(x)), diff(c(x, n)))
  x
}

makeparts(c(20, 30, 58), 100)
```

How would I rewrite this function using dplyr? I am pretty good in the tidyverse but never learned base R. I don't even know what that function is doing above. If I see it in tidyverse syntax I can understand the function (*probably*). Which is my ultimate goal.

All the tidyverse verbs make sense, but this [, x] [[df]] stuff doesn't.

Comment: `filter` is for data frames, you'd be much better off understanding the base R functions, the role of `dplyr` or `tidyverse` packages is to complement the base functions, not replace them, though it does replace a few functions with close equivalents.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper am eager to learn base R , on top of Vim, SQL, LaTeX, Linux command line, etc. But great advice, especially for others too. Thank you.

Comment: I understand that it can be overwhelming, but believe me, understanding `[` and `[[` is at the top of the list for `R`, tidyverse or not.

Comment: A more broad suggestion: if you don't understand the function, rebuild it by adding in one line at a time, running it, and seeing what happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x` looks like it is a vector. The first step uses `unique`, which would be the same as `distinct` in the tidyverse. The next line uses the `[` operator, which is used to index a vector or matrix. The value inside of `[ ]` should (for all intents and purposes) evaluate to a vector of `TRUE` or `FALSE` values or numbers. This is the same as `filter` in the tidyverse. The next line uses `order` on `x`, which is the same as `arrange`. The last step does two things: 1) it repeats the values from `seq_along(x)`, which, in this example, will be 1, 2, 3, and 4. It then concats `x` and `n` together, which gives `c(0, 20, 30, 58, 100)` and then runs `diff` on them, which will take the second element and subtract the first, take the third element and subtract the second, etc. This gives us `c(20, 10, 28, 42)` because (20-0) = 20, (30-20) = 10, and so forth. This last step is what could be achieved in the tidyverse using the `lag` function. The `rep` function does not have a direct tidyverse equivalent. As was mentioned in the comments above, this cannot be converted to tidyverse functions because those are for dataframes and you have a vector. I agree that you should learn base R. You can only get so far with the tidyverse.

## UPDATE:

Adding a tidyverse version of this code by request.

```
makeparts <- function(x, n) {
    x <- unique(c(0, x))
    x <- x[x >= 0 & x < n]
    x <- x[order(x)]
    x <- rep(c(seq_along(x)), diff(c(x, n)))
    x
}

makeparts_tidyverse <- function(x, n) {
    df = data_frame(x = c(0, x)) %>%
        distinct() %>%
        filter(x >= 0 & x < n) %>%
        arrange(x) %>%
        bind_rows(data_frame(x = n)) %>%
        mutate(lag_x = lag(x)) %>%
        mutate(y = x - lag_x) %>%
        filter(!is.na(y))
    rep(seq_along(df$x), df$y)
}

> makeparts(c(20, 30, 58), 100)
  [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [21] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
 [41] 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4
 [61] 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
 [81] 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4

> makeparts_tidyverse(c(20, 30, 58), 100)
  [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [21] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
 [41] 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4
 [61] 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
 [81] 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
```

Comment: Thank you for this well explained answer. Can you humor me and write `makeparts` in the closest thing you can to `tidyverse` syntax? I am very eager to learn base-R and will. It's just I also need to learn Vim, LaTeX, SQL and a lot of things ahhhhh!!!! :) but I enjoy it. In the meantime tidyverse is very powerful and too easy to use.

Comment: Welcome to world of data analysis, haha! Steep learning curve, but when it all comes together it's so satisfying. Let me try my best to convert this to a tidyverse thing.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a reformatted version using more tidyverse-like code :

```
x %>% 
  unique %>%
  keep(~.>=0 & .<n) %>%
  sort %>%
  c(0,.,n) %>%
  diff %>%
  list(lengths = ., values = seq_along(.)) %>%
  inverse.rle

# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
# [31] 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4
# [61] 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
# [91] 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
```